# Бэкап MySql и отпрака на почту

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Как организовать бэкап БД на email ?

Answer (score 2):

До переезда в собственное облако я использовал http://www.backup2mail.com/

Сейчас же использую mysqldump и складываю локально и на удаленный фтп.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ mysqldump необходимые_параметры | mail -s 'это бэкап' ваш@адр.ес
```

Answer (score 0):

Важно понимать ограничение размера вложения внутри почтового сервера.
Делать бэкап базы данных и отправлять его на почту изначально неверный подход.

Зарегистрируйте облачный диск (Яндекс Диск, Гугл диск или любой другой) и сохраняйте ваши бэкапы прямо на него.

Для себя я выбрал Яндекс диск (изза возможности загружать файлы по http с помощью REST API).

Если решитесь загружать на Яндекс, [эта статья поможет понять как получить доступ к нему с вашего сервера](http://influunt.ru/oauth-yandex-register-application-howto).